# Javascript - efficient way to store coordinates for big data set (to be able to search by value)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

I have two dimensional coordinates, like `(0, 1), (0, 2)`, `(2, 3)` and so on. At first I thought to simply use arrays like `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 3]]`. But then I ran into problems when I needed to look up coordinate by value.

I could implement search for array of arrays, but then I would need to iterate over all items to check for match (worse case scenario).

For example if I needed to lookup `0, 2` coordinate, I could not use `arr.indexOf(value)`, because value is an array. Then I thought to simply store coordinates as strings like `arr.push('01')`.

But then I need to make computations using those coordinates. So I would need to convert it to integers, compute and then convert it back.

Is there some better approach where you can have efficient lookup, without sacrificing data itself (like converting it to string)?

Comment: are the coordinates after calculation invalid/different?

Comment: No. But when using coords, I would need it to be as pair of integers. And then potentially store like that. Or I would need to convert from one type to another if its not really viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an object with properties based on the coordinates, like this:

```js
var coords = [[0, 2], [0, 1], [3, 2]];
var obj = {};

var setCoord = function (coord, value) {
  obj["c" + coord[0] + coord[1]] = { coord: coord, value: value};
};

var getCoord = function (coord) {
  return obj["c" + coord[0] + coord[1]];
};

setCoord(coords[0], "First coord");
setCoord(coords[1], "Second coord");
setCoord(coords[2], "Third coord");

var someCoord = getCoord(coords[2]);
document.body.innerHTML = `Coordinate: ${someCoord.coord}, Value: ${someCoord.value}`;
```

This way, you won't have to loop over every coordinate, and you can link as much data to the coordinate as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested objects for a fast loopup if the coordinates exists

```js
function check([x, y]) {
    return (x in coords) && (y in coords[x]);
}

var data = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 3]],
    coords = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(([x, y]) => {
    coords[x] = coords[x] || Object.create(null);
    coords[x][y] = true;                          // or any other needed value
});

console.log(check([0, 2]));
console.log(check([0, 0]));
console.log(coords);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would store the data in a one-dimensional array. Even indices for the x-value of a point, odd indices for the y-value. Using the following functions, you can get the index of a point (x, y), or get the x and y value of a point at a certain index:

```js
var points = [
//x, y
  0, 1, 
  0, 2, 
  2, 3
];

var findIndexOf = function (x, y) {
  return Math.round(
    points.findIndex((el, i) => i % 2 === 0 && el === x && points[i + 1] === y) / 2
  );
};

var getXValueFromIndex = function (index) {
  return points[index * 2];
};

var getYValueFromIndex = function (index) {
  return points[index * 2 + 1];
};

var index = findIndexOf(0, 2); // the index of (0, 2) in the array
console.log(index); // (0, 2) is the second point in the points array

var x = getXValueFromIndex(index);
var y = getYValueFromIndex(index);
console.log(x, y); // logs (0, 2)
```

That way, you don't have to create an array for each point.